# What is the best way to re-write Catalog Search Results?

Tags: catalogsearch, seo, advanced-search, .htaccess

We currently have a site that serves search results like the following:
http://www.domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=firstparam+otherparam+stuff

Ideally, we'd like it to serve it via: /firstparam+otherparam+stuff
We full recongize that the + is a reserved character, what we our goal is to use it.

We have the following htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,NE,R=301]
```

Now we have /firstparam+otherparam+stuff

How do we actually get the catalogsearch to run on this query?

Comment: What is anout sorting and pager params?

Comment: And may i know the goal of the customization?

Comment: Sorting/pager can be left on the main results page.  The initial goal is to have the url end up like:
domain.com/firstparam+otherparam+stuff
And have that return catalog search results rather than 404

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to and maybe even cant do this via a webserver rewrite.

A possible way is to add a new Router to the router chain.

config.xml:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <web>
            <routers>
                <search_rewrite>
                    <area>frontend</area>
                    <class>Search_Rewrite_Controller_Router_Redirect</class>
                </search_rewrite>
            </routers>
        </web>

    </default>
<config>
```

the here referenced class extends from Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard and needs to implement the ->match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request) method.

You need to ensure it is the last router executed.

then you can do a redirect with such a code:

```
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect( "some_constructed_url_thingy", 301 )
            ->sendResponse();
        $request->setDispatched(true);
        return true;
```